# Play 2.0 autocomplete reverse routing not working

Tags: jquery, html, scala, autocomplete, playframework-2.0

I'm having difficulties getting an autocomplete search box to work with Play 2.0. I'm trying to do the same thing as described in [this article](http://www.lunatech-research.com/archives/2011/07/05/jquery-ui-ajax-autocomplete-playframework), only with Play 2.0.

Basically, I defined an action:

```
def autocompleteSearch(term : String) = Action {
    // Do something to get a list of suggestions
    val list = ...
    // Reply with list
    Ok(Json.toJson(list))
}
```

I added a route in the routes file:

```
GET     /autocompleteSearch      controllers.Application.autocompleteSearch(term: String)
```

I created an autocomplete script:

```
$(function() {
    /*
     * Autocomplete for populating an input field with a value from the server.
     */
    $('input.autocomplete').each( function() {
        var $input = $(this);
        var serverUrl = $input.data('url');
        $(this).autocomplete({ source:serverUrl });
    });
});
```

And I insert the following somewhere on the page:

```
<input name="search" class="autocomplete" data-url="@{routes.Application.autocompleteSearch()}">
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work! I get the following compilation error:

```
not enough arguments for method autocompleteSearch: (term: String)play.api.mvc.Call. Unspecified value parameter term.
```

If I do this, I get the following error:

```
<input name="search" class="autocomplete" data-url="@{routes.Application.autocompleteSearch}">

missing arguments for method autocompleteSearch in class ReverseApplication; follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
```

Treating it as partially applied does not produce the result I want since the produced HTML looks like this:

```
<input name="search" class="autocomplete" data-url="&lt;function1&gt;">
```

I end up having to supply a dummy argument to get the reverse route to work:

```
<input name="search" class="autocomplete" data-url="@{routes.Application.autocompleteSearch( "" )}">
```

But then my autocomplete is useless because it always call the function with an empty string...

Did anyone manage to get this to work?

Thanks in advance for your help!

==

Follow-up question:

Alright. So I followed the doc and defined this in Application.scala:

```
def javascriptRoutes = Action {
    import routes.javascript._
    Ok(
        Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRouter")(
            routes.javascript.Application.autocompleteSearch
        )
    ).as("text/javascript")
}
```

I added this script to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Application.javascriptRoutes"></script>
```

Now, how do I modify my input field to connect the dots?

Is it:

```
<input name="search" class="autocomplete" data-url="jsRouter.controllers.Application.autocompleteSearch">
```

or

```
<input name="search" class="autocomplete" data-url="jsRouter.controllers.Application.autocompleteSearch().ajax()">
```

?

Neither seems to work!

I must say, I'm either very very dumb that I can't figure this out, or there is a *major* lack of documentation on this feature...

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add javascript routes.  Just add a default parameter to your route entry like

`GET  /autocompleteSearch      controllers.Application.autocompleteSearch(term: String ?= "")`

It will work

Answer (score 0):

This question needs to be reworded (the word autocomplete in the title is misleading) and retagged (you're probably looking for `playframework-2.0` as opposed to `playback`).

Regarding reverse routing, there do not appear to be enough walkthrough tutorials, however there is a [sample project](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/scala/zentasks) supplied by the Play! team that should get you going.